# Failed to get value of jquery plugin in asp.net textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, textbox

i have included a jquery datepicker plugin in my web forms application in asp.net , what i failed to do so is to get the datevalue in my textbox control i have looked up for the answers but according to that  have to give my text box the id of my span id but its still not working. any clue where i'm going wrong??

below is the jquery plugin code i included in date-time-selecterimg.inc

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="calendarPicker/jquery.calendarPicker.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendarPicker/jquery.calendarPicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendarPicker/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<div id="dsel2" style="width:340px"></div>
<br>
  <span id="wtf"></span>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var calendarPicker2 = $("#dsel2").calendarPicker({
    monthNames:["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    dayNames: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    //useWheel:true,
    //callbackDelay:500,
    years:-1,
    months:1,
    days:4,
    showDayArrows:true,
    callback:function(cal) {
    $("#wtf").html();
    }});
  </script>
```

i tried to use my span as a textbox i.e  , but it still doesn't work.

thats how my aspx page looks like

```
 <h2>Pick A Day</h2>
        <% 
                Response.WriteFile("components/date-time-selecterimg.inc");
            %>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about trying on your callback?

```
callback:function(cal) {
   $("#wtf").html($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: i didn't get it , you mean to say like this

    callback:function(cal) {
   $('input[id$=wtf]').html($(this).val());
}

Comment: sorry. yes like that.

Comment: i mean no. inside you callback function is `$("#wtf").html($(this).val());`

Comment: sorry didn't get you , what should i do in my callback function??

Comment: :).   right now you have this `callback:function(cal) {
    $("#wtf").html();
    }` try changing it to the above code.

Comment: i've tried it but still the value isn't appearing on textbox on my aspx page i included a <asp:textbox id="wtf" runat="server"> , Any mistakes here?